# Vanilla JS problem with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have a problem with **getElementById** and **getElementsByClassName**.

This code works fine

```
document.getElementById("dropdown-menu1").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            alert("click outside");
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

But when I try to use it with **getElementsByClassName** it's stop working.

```
var menu1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
        document.menu1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        alert("click outside");
        event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

I don't know why. I get no error.

Comment: FYI `menu1` and `document.menu1` have no relation at all. I would also be very surprised if you weren't getting an error like _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"_

Comment: [*getElementsByClassName*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [live *NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), whereas [*getElementById*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns a single element (or null).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally I can solved using getElementById.